# SwiftUI @FocusState when view appears

Tags: swiftui

How can I focus on a specific text field when the view appears? I have a basic form where I want the title field is be focused when the modal displays. I have the following code which achieves this but there has to be a cleaner/better way. Can I set the initial value of a `@FocusState var` to a field or a boolean that then selects the text field when the view appears?

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Title", text: $viewModel.title)
                        .focused($titleIsFocused)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("New List")
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.6) {
                    titleIsFocused = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that I have seen. There have been a bunch of tweets about this issue, and your code is the answer they have come up with.

Comment: Okay, I thought so. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy....this seems like a total mishap on Apple's part but oh well.

Comment: I read a tweet yesterday where someone marveled at how many things in SwiftUI were solved by `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)`. I hope someone does come up with an answer...

Comment: Yeah, well `onAppear` is actually called when the `View` is added to the memory graph as opposed to when it actually appears on the screen which is probably a cause of confusion for many of us.

Comment: Not so much confusion as irritation. Try determining when a particular list row is visible...